# Using the read method from StringReader

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is:

- Create a `StringReader` object using "Hello" string.
- Use the `read` method to read the characters, one by one, from the string.
- Determine how I can tell whether the last character of the string has been read.

So far, I have:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OneAtATime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringReader sr = new StringReader("Hello");
    public int read();
  }
}
```

I realize my code is doing essentially nothing at the moment as the value of my local variable is not used (upon other things). I'm just absolutely lost as for how I should go about finishing this & I'm struggling to follow the Java API.

Comment: What does the javadoc of the read() method say? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#read--

Answer (score 1):

As of JDK 9, you can experiment with `JShell`, which can help you interpret what the Java API documentation is telling you:

```
C:\>"\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\jshell.exe"
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> var sr = new StringReader("Hello");
sr ==> java.io.StringReader@ae45eb6

jshell> for(;;) {
   ...>   int i = sr.read();
   ...>   if (i < 0) break;
   ...>   System.out.println((char) i);
   ...> }
H
e
l
l
o

jshell> sr.read();
$3 ==> -1

jshell>
```